# Magento 2 Add to wish list return to the product detail page

Tags: magento, magento2

Currently in Magento 2 after add the product to wish list it move to the wish list page. I am trying to move it back to the product detail page. So for it i try to override the Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add with the di preference

```
<preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add"
            type="Eguana\CustomWishlist\Controller\Rewrite\Index\Add" />
```

And for it my controller is like this

```
namespace Eguana\CustomWishlist\Controller\Rewrite\Index;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class Add extends \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add
{


    public function __construct(Action\Context $context, \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, \Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface $wishlistProvider, ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository, Validator $formKeyValidator)
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $customerSession, $wishlistProvider, $productRepository, $formKeyValidator);
    }

    /**
     * Adding new item
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect
     * @throws NotFoundException
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CyclomaticComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedLocalVariable)
     */
    public function execute()
    {
      echo 'abc';
    }
}
```

My module.xml file is like this

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Eguana_CustomWishlist" setup_version="2.1.3">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Wishlist" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

But it is still calling the Magento Wishlist module controller. Can you please let me know is there any issue in my overriding process? Thank you very much.

Comment: You can try these options to achieve the functionality. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/326239/44915

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento2 Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add is overriden by another core module MultipleWishlist module Magento\MultipleWishlist\Controller\Index\Add so if you want to override the wishlist add controller then you should override the MultipleWishlist add controller.

I hope it will work for you and will save your time.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Abbas

In your module di.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">        
    <preference for="Magento\MultipleWishlist\Controller\Index\Add" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\MultipleWishlist\Add" />
    <preference for="Magento\Wishlist\Controller\Index\Add" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Wishlist\Add" />
</config>
```

Note : In override controller of MultipleWhislist

```
 namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\MultipleWishlist;

 use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
 use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Action;
 use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey\Validator;
 use Magento\MultipleWishlist\Model\WishlistEditor;
 use Magento\Wishlist\Controller\WishlistProviderInterface;

 class Add extends \Vendor\Module\Controller\Wishlist\Add
{
```

It's working fine.